# Adding 2 images and a popup script to an imageslider single <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox, slider

I'm using a [pikachoose](http://pikachoose.com) slider that uses lists:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="pikachoose">
         <ul id="pikame">
              <li><a href="www.gohere.com"><img src="image.jpg/></a></li>
              <li><a href="www.gohere.com"><img src="image2.jpg/></a></li>
         </ul>
</div>
```

I also have a seperate jQuery [fancybox](http://fancybox.net) that opens a youtube video popup:

```
<div id="center">
    <a class="fancybox" href="youtubelink"><img src="playbutton-100px.jpg" />
</a>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is add this bottom code to one upper `<li>` so there'd be 2 images on that list. And when clicking on the 2nd image (playbutton.jpg) it should popup the video. The problem I'm facing is even if I only copy the link  from the bottom, without the 2nd image, it won't start jQuery popup and links to youtube directly.

[Demo](http://www.nobodyfilm.org/inteks.html) - the play button is across all images as it's not part of a single

Comment: So you want the play button on the page which launches the youtube in a popup? that appears to be already working? http://i.imgur.com/4p1UwF7.jpg

Comment: The play button is across all the images though. I wish to have it *only* on a single image (<li>).

Comment: you are missing to add the class `fancybox` to the anchor inside the the `li` element